# Right place to put questions about quality of code?

Tags: discussion

I have some piece of code and I'd like to have its quality checked by users, if I am using good patterns, if it is readable, etc.

Is Stack Overflow a good place for it?

Answer (score 15):

Stack Overflow is *not* the right place to ask this sort of question.

Your question *may* be on topic for Code Review, but...

## [You should check to see if it would be suitable there *first*.](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/9874)

A quick elimination round:  if your code *doesn't* work, it's likely not on topic there.